# New Twitter Tweet Fetcher only showing 1 tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using the following code to show my latest tweets from the new twitter API. I've got it working perfectly, however, no matter what I do I can only get it to show one tweet, how can I make it show 5 tweets?

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var twitterFetcher=function(){var d=null;return{fetch:function(a,b){d=b;var c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/"+a+"?&lang=en&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd="+Math.random()    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)},callback:function(a){var b=document.createElement("div");b.innerHTML=a.body;a=b.getElementsByClassName("e-entry- title");d(a)}}}();

twitterFetcher.fetch('345901443028488192', function(tweets){
// Do what you want with your tweets here! For example:
var x = tweets.length;
var n = 0;
var numtweets = 5;
var element = document.getElementById('tweets');
var html = '<ul id="tweetul">';
if (tweets[n].innerHTML) {
  html += '<li><img src="images/myicon.png" class="twittericon"/>' + tweets[n].innerHTML + '</li>';
} else {
  html += '<li><img src="images/myicon.png" class="twittericon"/>' + tweets[n].textContent + '</li>';
}
n++;
html += '</ul>';
element.innerHTML = html;
});
</script>
```

Comment: You set `n` to zero, then increment it once, and exit the function. Did you forget to add a loop?

Comment: Hi Juhana, how do i add the loop the ccode above, I've been playing with this for hours now

Comment: http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/loops.php

Answer (score 1):

You are not looping. You increment `n`, but you're never going back to the code above it.

Answer (score 1):

you can get a new version of the api here :
http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.CAN6FObk.dpbs
then you can write this :

> twitterFetcher.fetch('345170787868762112', 'example1', 1, true);

change with "1" in the code above count of tweets you wanted.

I hope you could help.